# Using a transformation to polar coordinates to integrate a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ over a disk.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If I'm integrating a function $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ over a disk $D$ (where $D = \left\{(x,y)\,|\,x^2 + y^2 \le s^2\right\}$), and I want to use the change of variables theorem to transform $f$ into a function in polar coordinates, like so: $$\iint_Df(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \iint_{D^*}r\tilde f(r,\theta)\,dr\,d\theta,$$ where $D^* = \left\{(r,\theta)\,|\,(0 \le r \le s)\,\land\, (0\le \theta \le 2\pi)\right\}$, how do I limit $\theta$ to ensure that the transformation from $D$ to $D^*$ is injective?  Do I have to compute the integral over the four unique quarter circles and add the results together, is it sufficient to integrate over the two unique semicircles and add the two results, or is it not even necessary to limit $\theta$ and I can just integrate directly over the circle?

Comment: The transformation is *almost injective* in the sense that the set of points for which it is not injective has zero measure, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you written relation between old and new variables and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the transformation $x=r\cos{\theta}$, $y=r\sin{\theta}$ is injective if $0 \leqslant \theta<2\pi$ and $r>0$. $r=0$ causes lots of problems because if $r=0$, every value of $\theta$ gives the same point $(0,0)$. As you probably know, however, the value of an integral is unchanged if we change the function at $1$ point, so we can disregard the point $r=0$ if we desire to make the transformation injective, with no loss.

However, in two dimensions, it doesn't matter if you exclude a *line* from the domain of integration (because you can cover it by a countable number of boxes, the total area of which can be as small as you like, and therefore the total contribution of the function integrated over this set can be made as small as you like, at least if it is continuous), so we can actually just use $0<\theta<2\pi$, $0<r<s$, which gives an injective transformation, which is also surjective after removing the lines $\theta=0$ and $r=s$, which actually, as I just explained, contribute a grand total nothing to the integral anyway.

Therefore, if you're worried about losing injectivity by covering a line or point twice in two dimensions, for integrable functions it doesn't actually matter. (Similarly in higher dimensions with objects of dimension strictly less than the dimension of the space: basically, if you have the integral of an integrable function and can cover the set by small enough boxes, you can ignore it. See also [measure zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set), which is a rigorous enunciation of this concept.

Comment: So, just to confirm, I can integrate over the circle directly without dividing it into smaller regions (e.g. quarter circles)?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.